# Where can I find the ANDROID_ID on my device?

Tags: imei, android-id

I know that you can find IMEI and MAC address and others by going to `Settings -> About phone -> Status`. You can also find IMEI by typing `*#06#` on the keypad. Is there any way to get the ANDROID_ID on the phone itself, as opposed to via this bit of code?

```
Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: [Where is the “android_id” stored and when it changes?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219757/218526)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this via `adb`. Does not require root, as far as I know (tested on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.1 built from AOSP source):

```
shell@android:/ $ content query --uri content://settings/secure --projection value --where "name='android_id'"              
  Row: 0 value=<your ID in hexadecimal>
```

Comment: If running via a terminal emulator app, root is required.

Comment: adb has more privileges than the local shell user. With Android 4.x (ICS and up), you can even do a full backup via ADB on an unrooted device -- which the shell user for sure cannot.

Answer (score 7):

`settings get secure android_id` from `adb shell` is the simplest, I find — no extraneous output and does not require root.  (From a regular terminal on the device, root is required.)

```
shell@mydevice:/ $ settings get secure android_id
0123456789abcdef
shell@mydevice:/ $
```

Comment: To get into adb shell: 1. Go to `android_sdk/platform-tools/` with cmd or other terminal. 2. `adb devices` to check if your mobile can be found through USB. 3. `adb shell`. 4. Run command in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

As [eldarerathis variant](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35660/16575) didn't work out for me, and I didn't want to install an app just for that, I've found a different way. Only possible drawback: It requires root.

```
adb shell
$ su
# cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases
# sqlite3 settings.db
sql> select * from secure where name='android_id';
26|android_id|1234567890abcdef1
```

The `android_id` is found in the third column here (anonymized in the example).

---

**EDIT:**

Note that this is *NOT* the `android_id` used by the Google apps. Google seems to have decided for some confusion here. For *Play Services*, there's a separate `android_id` stored by *GTalk*, as [pointed out by a blog post](http://blog.codepainters.com/2012/01/17/how-to-obtain-gtalk-android-id/) (also see [this answer by HassleFixes](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/82820/16575), who is the autor of [StripSearch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hasslefixes.stripsearch), and thankfully pointed this out in the comments):

- call up your dialer
- dial `*#*#8255#*#*`
- watch out for "Device ID"
- remove the leading `android-`
- what remains, is the `android_id` used by *Google Services*

I've verified that: the `android_id` retrieved this way works fine on a device with no Google-Apps installed (used with the *BlankStore* provided by the *NOGAPPS* project).

Comment: `*#*#8255#*#*` doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer has `$ content query --uri content://settings/secure --projection value --where "name='android_id'"` in it

If you're executing this from shell then you'll need to escape the quotes around android_id else they get interpreted and the SQL statement doesn't have them, resulting in an unknown column.

My full command from bash looks line...
`$ adb shell content query --uri content://settings/secure --projection value --where "name=\'android_id\'"`

^ Not enough reputation to comment on the answer that suggested it above

Comment: Kind of. @eldarerathis's answer started up a shell on the device with `adb shell`, and then ran another command within that shell. This works fine without escaping the quotes. Your answer is running a single command on the main machine; for this you do need to escape the quotes.