# Can I Change My Device Info For Reach Another Version of an App On Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

For example, I have a snapdragon phone. But I want to reach an app's intel version too. Because tablet of my litte cousin can not reach to WiFi. And he want to download a free game. When I download and give it to my cousin, game won't work cause different proccessor(intel thing). So I want to get this app's intel version. How can I do this?

I think its possible with edit my device info but I dont know which info and to what.

Edit: And if I edit my build prop's ro.product.cpu.api, will my device get hard brick?

Comment: What good does it do? Can you give some background? The Intel version wouldn't run on ARM. Do you e.g. need the `.apk` for some Intel device that has no Playstore access? It's no good idea to manipulate your device for that, as for the side-effects to be expected.

Comment: I'll edit build prop then reboot. Download the app and after 5 minute recover my old build.prop. In this 5 minute, I'll open just Play Store. If I edit this, will my device get hard brick?

Comment: In the worst case, the device won't boot up successfully anymore, and you'll neet to repair your `build.prop` via recovery or reflash the ROM. But again, please [edit] your question and add the background: What do you need that for? This is not a forum to discuss things – and I have good reason to believe this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). What is your final goal? What do you need the Intel `.apk` for? there might be other (and less dangerous) ways to achieve that.

Comment: Okay edited the question

Comment: Thought so :) See [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/122286/16575): [Raccoon](https://github.com/onyxbits/Raccoon) is your answer. No device modification. Runs on any computer with Java installed. I'm using this myself. // as for the `build.prop` part: Please ask that as separate question. Q&A sites work best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've already pointed out in my comments on the question, modifying your device's `build.prop` to appear as a different architecture is a very bad idea. It won't "hard-brick" your device, but certainly will have side-effects you won't like (e.g. the device might refuse to boot up at all – not sure what *exactly* will happen, as I was not yet bold enough to try; if you really want to know that, either try (not recommended if you don't know a way out then) or ask that as a separate question).

---

Concerning your real goal: As pointed out in [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/122286/16575), you can use [Raccoon](https://github.com/onyxbits/Raccoon) on your computer for that.

While the other question focuses on apps you've bought, *Raccoon* of course also works for free apps. For different device architectures, you will need to create different profiles: [DummyDroid](http://www.onyxbits.de/dummydroid) can create the required "GSF IDs for mock up devices" if you don't know the one of yours, based on the given device's `build.prop`. If that doesn't work out, or you want to use the "real ID", please [see my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/82550/16575) on how to obtain it from your device (or from that of your cousin).

Comment: *concerning your real goal* GOT IT! I was thinking about "oh god.. why he wondering it.." Thank you a lot :D

Comment: :) Glad I could help! If this solves your "real issue" (LOL), please consider "accepting" it (tick the green check-mark next to the answer) so others can identify the post as solution. Enjoy Raccoon!

Comment: One more little question, how can I download intel version of an app?

Comment: As I wrote: by using a profile based on the GSF ID of an Intel device. As with the Playstore app, *Raccoon* will only show apps matching your device.

Comment: Didn't see after **While the other..**

Comment: *LOL* Yeah, it's useful to read the full answer before asking for additional details #D Good luck then! // Btw: if the app doesn't show up then, it might not be available for Intel. Can happen, so be prepared.

Comment: @Izzy Market helper on the Play store Could help too- it configures a false build.prop that makes Google think your device is something else, while leaving your actual build.prop to chill. It also allows for the installation of apps from the play store in this way. OP could just pretend to be a device with a Intel CPU.

Comment: @DanBrown I know *[Market Helper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2146216)* – but for one it's not available *on* the Playstore, two it was last updated in 8/2014 (AFAIK back then there weren't any x86 devices around running Android, so not sure if this would be supported). On the "pro side", it doesn't touch the `build.prop`, so there shouldn't be much side-effects :)

Comment: @Izzy Oh. Odd. Maybe they removed it recently, I remember using the play store to get it.

Comment: @DanBrown That must have been pretty long ago. [My corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets#group_8) has it as "supplemental link" for ages, as the app wasn't on Playstore. Which means, it hasn't been there for at least 2+ years. // Nevermind: It's not there now, and it hasn't been updated for a long time.