# Where is the "android_id" stored and when does it change?

Tags: android-id

I want to build a `device_id` with `android_id`, any one knows the answer to these three questions?

- Where is the `android_id` value stored?
- When is the `android_id` value initialized, i.e. the first time the value is set?
- In which cases does the `android_id` value change?

Comment: please see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554019/308316), especially the links to developer.android.com.

Comment: [Where can I find the ANDROID_ID on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35659/218526)

Answer (score 7):

> - Where is the `android_id` value stored?

On Android 5 and earlier this was stored in `secure` namespace of device Settings. So you can extract using:

```
~$ content query --uri content://settings/secure --projection value --where "name='android_id'"
```

Or:

```
~$ settings get secure android_id
```

Or directly read the `secure` table of `settings.db` database file. For device owner:

```
~# sqlite3 /data/user/0/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db 'select * from secure where name="android_id"'
```

Since Android 6 [settings are saved in `xml` files](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/683914bfb13908bf3). For device owner:

```
~# grep android_id /data/system/users/0/settings_secure.xml
```

Since Android 8, `android_id` is [*"unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device"*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) so as to deny [*"developers the ability to track users across multiple applications"*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5514fb7aba781d8eabbbfc27a5d27a6b3a447b40). These unique IDs are stored in `/data/system/users/<User_ID>/settings_ssaid.xml`.

> - When `android_id` value init, the first time set the value?
> - Which case does the `android_id` value change?

As evident, `android_id` *"is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device"* unless a factory reset is performed which clears all settings.

On Android 8+ the app specific `android_id` *"value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes"*.

Keeping all in view it doesn't seem a good idea to build a `device_id` with `android_id`.