# Is it possible to change the Android ID with root access? (On Android 10)

Tags: android-10, magisk, edxposed, android-id

I have an Android 10 phone (Motorola Moto G9 Play) and I want to change the Android ID (I think that's what apps use to identify you sometimes).
I have a cell phone with: ROOT + Magisk + EdXposed
I always changed my "Android ID" using "Titanium Backup". But there is currently no option to change.
Is it possible to change the "Android ID" just using a few tools, command line, applications, something that can modify the "Android ID"?
Please, I need it so much.
Reason: Some applications when they are going to ban accounts, they block the "Android ID" and I need to modify it and then use it again!
(By Google Translator, sorry!) =(

Comment: [Is it possible to change Android ID without root access nor factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233861/218526)

Comment: [Where is the “android_id” stored and when does it change?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219757/218526)

Comment: Thank you very much for the 2 responses.

Comment: If I change an application's SSAID from "aaaabbbbcccc1111" to "aaaabbbbcccc2222" for example. After I update it, or reset the settings, does it lose "aaaabbbbcccc2222" and go back to the original SSAID "aaaabbbbcccc1111"?

Comment: What exactly happens if I delete the line with (name = "userkey")?

Comment: Your device already uses the app-specific persistent [ANDROID_ID](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html?m=1). I have not checked the AOSP source code how this is implemented but based on your experience I would assume that for each app that has been ever installed in some SQlite or XML file the generated ANDOIRD_ID is kept.