# How do I change the AndroidID?

Tags: root-access, factory-reset, titanium-backup, android-id

My Android ID has changed since a factory reset. Now some apps/services don't work. Besides using Titanium Backup, how can I restore/change back to the previous Android ID? I already know what the ID is.

Android 7 | Rooted

Comment: Last time I checked there were a few apps in Play Store that can change the Android ID on rooted devices.

Comment: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=device+id

Comment: May help: [Where is the "android_id" stored and when does it change?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219757/218526) and [Is it possible to change Android ID without root access nor factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233861/218526)

Answer (score 0):

For those who may not know this:
Android ID is an unique ID to each device. It is used to identify your device for market downloads, specific gaming applications that needs to identify your device (so that they know it's a device that was used to pay for the application) and such.

If you don’t have a rooted device, then it would be a little difficult to change the device ID. You’ll have to fully format your device data to change your Android phone’s device ID. As the device ID is generated when you first set up the device, resetting the phone will change the Android device ID automatically.

If you have a rooted device, then changing the device ID is just a two-tap process. You can use any reliable Android device ID changer app and it will change the device ID with a random one with just two taps.
the app I used before is **"Device ID Changer by Silver Lab"** but it's no longer available in google play but you can find it by searching in google.
the package name is: **com.silverlab.app.deviceidchanger.free**

hope it helps.

Comment: The OP doesn't want a random id.  They want to revert to a previous id.