# I changed android device ID using adb but apps still see the old device id

Tags: adb, root-access, android-12

I followed these 2 commands to change android device ID

```
./adb.exe shell settings get secure android_id 
// Returns old device id

./adb.exe shell settings put secure android_id 1b32af358342cb24
// Passes without error

./adb.exe shell settings get secure android_id 
// Returns 1b32af358342cb24

Restart my phone now.

./adb.exe shell settings get secure android_id 
// Returns 1b32af358342cb24
```

Now when I use device id checker apps from play store, they still show the old device id. What should I do? I don't have root though. My phone is Oneplus 8T.

Comment: Since Android 8.0 each Android app gets a unique android_id. I just checked android_id in two apps and they each report different android_id on Android 10. See relevant info in this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219757/96277 // Since each app sees a different android_id, what are you hoping to achieve by changing android_id in secure settings?

Comment: @Firelord Yes. I am aware of it. But if I change the main android id, the unique id for those apps should change too. Right? That's what I want to do

Comment: You'd have to look into the source code of Android to figure out if secure settings' android_id has anything to do with the unique android_id each app sees.